# Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, printing

I want to Print receipt page on loading page in firefox

Firefox shows following error..

Use of `getPreventDefault()` is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead.
error source line:

```
src.getPreventDefault && src.getPreventDefault() ) ? returnTrue : returnFalse;
```

> NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component returned failure code: 0x80040111
>   (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIDOMWindow.print] error source line:

---

```
print();
```

code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    print_doc();
    $("#Submit").click(function() {
        $("#goBack").hide();
        $("#printRow").hide();
        print();
        $("#goBack").show();
        $("#printRow").show();
    });
});

function print_doc() {
    $("#goBack").hide();
    $("#printRow").hide();
    print();
    $("#goBack").show();
    $("#printRow").show();
}
```

I want to print my receipt before showing "goBack", and "printRow" id's but not working

Comment: Also, you're better off using window.print(); - Furthermore, you current code Prints the Screen twice

Comment: You're asking two different questions here. Unless you intend to change the title of your post, you should accept MackieeE's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create new css with **media type print**

```
<style media="print">
#goBack,#printRow {
   display:none;
}
</style>
```

used this code

**print :**

Intended for printed documents (applies to docs viewed in print preview mode too).

[CSS Media Type](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmedia.shtml)

Comment: I want to shows these id  after printing #goBack,#printRow   but showing Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead.
error source line:
 

src.getPreventDefault && src.getPreventDefault()) ? returnTrue : returnFalse;

Answer (score 9):

Upgrade both your versions of [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/) & [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) version from `1.6.4` to a more recent version.

This was filed as a bug in Firefox in FF11 & Patched as a result:

[Bug #707677: getPreventDefault(); deprecated](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=707677)

As after all, the error messages refer to lines of source code that are completely unrelated to your code.

Comment: "Upgrade both your versions of Firefox & jQuery version from 1.6.4 to a more recent version"  its very help full -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-Also thes media Css helped me            @media print {
  #goBack, #printRow {
     display: none;
  }
}

Comment: But it was `#goBack, #printRow { display:none; }` that fixed it for you?

Comment: I get this from jQuery 1.10.2, currently the latest on the 1.x family.

Comment: @romkyns I've recently got this happening on sometimes with the latest version of Chrome too.

Comment: Still occuring in Firefox 31.0 and jQuery v1.9.1.

Comment: Occuring in Firefox 33.1 and jQuery v.1.9.1

Comment: Should be fixed in jQuery 1.11 -- see [this ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14282).

Answer (score 4):

I also get this warning in the latest FF and jQuery.  Don't worry about it, it'll get fixed upstream before it causes any problems.

As for your code, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Submit").click(function() {
        var btns = $('#goBack, #printRow');
        btns.hide(function () {
            window.print();
            btns.show();
        });
    });
});
```

.hide()  is asynchronous, meaning that the next line of code may be executed before the browser has had a chance to execute it.  So you might be printing before the elements are hidden.  By sticking the print inside of .hide()'s callback, you are sure it is hidden when you print.

As another poster mentioned, though, CSS media types are probably a better way to do this:

```
@media print {
  #goBack, #printRow {
     display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it resolved by replacing the latest version of js , visit jquery site and replace with the latest jquery if required .map js too