# Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead. Why I'm getting this error and what's the solution for it?

Tags: jquery, migration, deprecated, preventdefault

Previously I was using jQuery 1.7.1 in my code. I was getting the above error.
Then I used the jQuery 1.11.1 straight from the google repository

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
</script>
```

but still I'm getting this error. How should I resolve this?

Due to this error my other jQuery functionality is also not working.

I researched a lot about the solution but every time I got the same solution of upgrading the jQuery version. But this is also not working for me.

Comment: Where is the code that throws error?

Comment: @Regent:It's not showing the code in console in firebug. It only giving this error/warning. It shows the file name but it doesn't contain any of such line of code into it. That's why I'm just clue less about this issue.

Comment: Is it warning or error? What file name does it show?

Comment: @Regent:the file which is currently opened in browser say xyz.php

Comment: There is no `getPreventDefault()` inside _jquery-1.11.1.min.js_. So the problem is either in your browser (looks like Firefox 24.0 has bug like this) or in your code (if you use `getPreventDefault()` or if you have included library which uses it).

Comment: @Regent:Let me check thoroughly then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175218/use-of-getpreventdefault-is-deprecated-use-defaultprevented-instead

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
event.originalEvent.defaultPrevented
```

As in:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.defaultPrevented) return;
    // continue
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I get this error with PHPStorm debugging with Firefox 2.8 when using jQuery, currently jquery-2.0.2.min.
On examining the file, it contains the following statement:

```
this.isDefaultPrevented=e.defaultPrevented||e.getPreventDefault&&e.getPreventDefault()?U:Y
```

if you change this to:

```
this.isDefaultPrevented=e.defaultPrevented?U:Y
```

the warning stops.

Answer (score 4):

I have also come across this problem and found that with jQuery 1.x the replacement

```
event.defaultPrevented;
```

does not work at all, but the original

```
event.getPreventDefault();
```

still works as expected but does throw a warning on Firebug. I guess someone somewhere expects everyone to upgrade to jQuery 2.x eventually. This shouldn't be a fatal or critical error for you, simply a warning, and in this instance that the replacement feature doesn't work on jQuery 1.x then it's suitable to bare this in mind but not act upon this warning.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and using Firefox's dev tools I realized I incorrectly commented something out in a hurry, forgetting to comment out the `</script>` also. Sometimes it the stupid little things.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the file locally.
Then if the problem is still there, open your jquery file and search for "`getPreventDefault`" and replace by "`defaultPrevented`".

Answer (score 0):

kindly check if the jquery.min.js is included twice. if yes then try to ignore local one so that you get latest file.
Actually I got same msg on myside so by debugging i found there were to jquery library was included twice.
hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is `getPreventDefault` in https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

The list of all versions https://code.jquery.com/jquery/

`getPreventDefault` is still in [1.8.3](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js), [1.9.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js), [1.10.2](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js), [1.11.0](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js)

And it's finally gone in [1.11.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js) of which [1.11.3](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js) is the latest version.