# How to return JSON from action

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I create a JSON object and return a JsonResult from my action (requested by `$.getJSON in Ajax`)

I write this in my action:

```
public JsonResult GetStudentInfo(int id)
    {
        var contactInfo = new Movie
        {
            FirstName = "Bob",
            LastName = "Cravens",
            Age = 23
        };
        return Json(contactInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and this is my script in view:

```
$("button").click(function () {
   var url = "/Home/GetStudentInfo";
   $.getJSON(url, { id:10 }, function (data) {
       $("#search").append("<div>" + data.FirstName + "</div>");
   });
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is not working? What errors do you get in the browsers console? Do you actually hit the controller method?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. _It does not work_ is not a useful statement

Comment: I have no error

Comment: Is it goes to dubug?. Put break point

Comment: in console just I have this warning "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead."

Comment: @Black_Hammer Please write your html also. If your button type is submit, then you should use `e.preventDefault()` in `click` event

Comment: in my html I just I have a <div> element and a <button> element inside it.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177305/use-of-getpreventdefault-is-deprecated-use-defaultprevented-instead-why-im

Comment: Please include the jquery.js file in `_Layout.cshtml` and JS code needs to be inside `$(document).ready(function(){ });`. Its working.

Comment: Show your html.

Comment: this is my Html code [link](http://uupload.ir/files/ohv2_sketch.png)

Comment: Put the code in the question! (not in comments, and not images). And you do not even have an element with `id="search"`

Comment: :)))) yes it was a Mistake Thank you for your help Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Your button click event is not firing.There is no selector. Write your code against id or class of button. Also ensure that the required jquery-{veraion}.js is loaded.

Something like that.

```
<input type="button" id="test" value="Click Me" />
```

and your js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").click(function () {
            var url = "/Home/GetStudentInfo";
            $.getJSON(url, { id: 10 }, function (data) {
                $("#search").append("<div>" + data.FirstName + "</div>");
            });
        });
 })
```

It is working for me. Please check.